# Intial Value to running total FastReport.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, fastreport

I am calculating a balance for debit and credit amount, i want to set the balance to a certain value, how can i make the running total start from a given value.

I tried initiating it from the code itself but it didn't work it sets the given value for all records, i want to set it for the first time only to affect only the first calculated value.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Please make sure you read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it will help you improve you questions and hence make it easier for others to answer your question
Please your code to the question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.